# Show spaces in option tag

Tags: php, css, html

I want to arrange my list as following:

```
Subject         Chapter         MCQ     Duration(min)
Physics 1            10          40               40
Chemistry 1           9          30               30
Math 1               10          40               40
Biology 1            12          40               20
```

So, I tried following:

```
<div style="font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode"">
    <?php
        include_once('funcs.php');
        $f = new funcs();
        $res = $f->get_ques(); 
        printf("%-'.20s", 'Subject');
        printf("%-'.20s", 'Chapter');
        printf("%-'.20s", 'Marks');
        printf("%-'.20s", 'Duration');
   ?>
   <br/>
   <select>
   <?php
       while( $q = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ) {
           echo '<option>', printf("%-'-20s", $f->get_sub($q['q_id'])), printf("%-'.20s", $q['chapter']), printf("%-'.20s", $q['mcq']), printf("%-'.20s", $q['time']), '</option>';
       }
   ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

And my output is:

[image]

Lines are zigzag. I want these lines to be strict. I tried to use fixed length font but failed. And I should remove these dots . as well. Anyone please help me.

Comment: Use a table instead, with radio buttons or checkboxes in one column to let the user select things. What you have is tabular data and cannot be used in the simple structure that a `select` element gives you.

Comment: another good solution. But I'll first go for select

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
echo '<option>', printf("%-'-20s", $f->get_sub($q['q_id'])), printf("%-'.20s", $q['chapter']), printf("%-'.20s", $q['mcq']), printf("%-'.20s", $q['time']), '</option>';
```

to

```
echo '<option>', printf("% /&nbsp20s", $f->get_sub($q['q_id'])), printf("% /&nbsp20s", $q['chapter']), printf("% /&nbsp20s", $q['mcq']), printf("% /&nbsp20s", $q['time']), '</option>';
```

use `&nbsp` for space.

Comment: He'll still need a fixed width font to make the columns line up.

Comment: Your solution is displaying `bsp20s6bsp20s6bsp20s6bsp20s6` on every option. Why?

Comment: @CoolBrain `&nbsp;` is the html entity that represents a space. Repeat spaces will not show up unless you use this.

Comment: then why I find this `bsp20s6bsp20s6bsp20s6bsp20s6` in each option?

Comment: @CoolBrain Sorry for late reply. Now you can use the edited code. Just forgot to escape the `&` character. :)

Comment: now it's `&nbsp20s8&nbsp20s8&nbsp20s8&nbsp20s8` in each option, :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `&nbsp;` for spaces not `-`.

Answer (score 0):

As such thing with different types and fonts would not possible as each character width is different from each other. There is only One way to do things required by you. In Options use Monospaced Font Courier or any other Monospaced font. I know the Courier has the same width of all characters. Just Change the font name to courier and view the required think needed by you.

Use style sheet prove the id is select and option and describe css rules as:

```
 <select id=abc>
     <option id=abc> def </option>
 </select>
```

and in css

```
 #abc {font-family:.......}.
```

The will be resolved

Comment: He's asking for a dropdown list.

Comment: As I know, Consolas is also a monospace font. `<option style="font-family: consolas">` this code do not change the font, actually no style is changing current font.